# Obtaining deep and REM sleep data from the Jawbone UP API?

Tags: jawbone

I realize this may have been asked before but my previous comment/question was never answered :(

Any update on Jawbone including REM sleep details in the sleep phases/ticks response? The Jawbone app shows all phases of sleep for a evening sleep event (awake, light, REM, deep/sound) so I'm confused as to why the endpoint doesn't return the same data (it only includes light, deep/sound combined, and awake)?

Comment: Hi Bob, I meant to reply to your comment on the earlier question. We have this on the roadmap, but there's isn't an ETA yet. I'll let you know when we have firmer plan.

Comment: @RAY Ok, thanks but I could really use that data now :( but happy to beta test it for my personal API (bobapi.com). Once it's rolled out, I'm assuming REM will be included in all historic data, not just sleep data moving forward?